# $_POST metacharacters?

Tags: php, post

in my $_POST, I have a variable whose name changes. the name is modify_0, but the number at the end changes depending on the button that was pressed.
Is there anyway to check what the number is for that variable in `$_POST`?

Say:

```
$_POST['modify_(check for number or any character)']
```

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more? I do not get what you are asking.

Comment: Do you have to use $_POST? Because (if i understood you correctly) i think it would be way more easier if you just use $_GET and add the parameter to the url.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the correct answers given above, I would recommend changing your code slightly so it's easier to work with.

Instead of having inputs with the format:

```
// works for all types of input
<input type="..." name="modify_1" />
<input type="..." name="modify_2" />
```

You should try:

```
<input type="..." name="modify[1]" />
<input type="..." name="modify[2]" />
```

This way, you can iterate through your data in the following way:

```
$modify = $_POST['modify'];
foreach ($modify as $key => $value) {
     echo $key . " => " . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This works especially well for multiselects and checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to iterate over all of the keys within the `$_POST` variable and take a look at their format:

```
$post_keys = array_keys( $_POST );
foreach($post_keys as $key){
  if ( strpos($key, 'modify_' ) != -1 ){
    // here you know that $key contains the word modify
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// First we need to see if there are any keys with names that start with
// "modify_". Note: if you have multiple values called "modify_X", this
// will take out the last one.
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (substr($key, 0) == 'modify_') {
    $action = $key;
  }
}

// Proceed to do whatever you need with $action.
```